# Trying to set the permissions of all files in a folder that includes the characters 'DATA' to Read-Write? Rocky linux

Tags: linux

I am trying to change the permission to only read and write of all the files in a specific folder but the file has to have the string "DATA" in it.

I tried using this command but I'm not sure how to filter it should I use grep?

`grep -nr DATA | chmod u=rw,g=rw,o=rw  *`

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments to your now deleted question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77334780/trying-to-set-the-permissions-of-all-files-in-a-folder-that-includes-the-charact):

```
grep -rl DATA "foldername" | xargs -n1 chmod =rw
```

... CAVEAT: this won't work if the filenames have spaces in them.

I strongly recommend reading a great deal of linux/unix toolchain tutorials and figuring out how tools work together before engaging with things in real life.

Your invocation changes EVERYTHING, but since `chmod` by default doesn't output anything, your `grep` does **nothing**.

What you really *need* to do is, as in my example, find the files that have `DATA` in them, and modify their permissions.

Comment: That's not limited to spaces. Other types of blanks, newline, single quotes, double quotes and backslashes would also be a problem. That would not work in zsh where `=rw` expands to the path of the `rw` command and `chmod =rw` is sensitive to the umask.

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively find each files in the directory an run `chmod` if a file contains string "DATA".

perm.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

grep -w "DATA" "$1" && chmod 666 "$1"
```

Use `find` to recursively search for regular files (thanks [Stephane](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/759486/trying-to-set-the-permissions-of-all-files-in-a-folder-that-includes-the-charact/759496#comment1447633_759496))

```
find <path/of/folder> -type f -exec bash </path/of/perm.sh> {} \;
```

Comment: Note that `[ -f` also returns true for symlinks to regular files and both `grep` and `chmod` will act on the target of the symlink. So for instance if there's a symlink to `/etc/shadow` in there and `/etc/shadow` contains `DATA` and you're running that as `root`, you'll end up making `/etc/shadow` world writeable.

Comment: Note that there's nothing bash-specific in that code (and you're using a `.sh` extension in the file). Using your system's `sh` would likely be more efficient and remove the need to install bash. sh and bash also support running inline scripts as in `find ... -exec sh -c 'if ...' sh {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using the GNU `-r` extension of `grep`¹, you could do:

```
grep -rlZ DATA . | xargs -r0 chmod a=rw
```

With `-l`, `grep` `l`ists the files that contain at least one line matching the regexp. With `-Z` (also a GNU extension), it prints the file paths NUL-delimited so that output can be post-processed.

`xargs -0`² splits that output on NULs to pass *as separate arguments* to the `chmod` utility. With `-r`², `xargs` doesn't run `chmod` at all if its input is empty (`grep` didn't report any file path).

To skip the files which already have `rw-rw-rw-` permissions:

```
find . -type f ! -perm a=rw -exec grep -lZ DATA {} + |
  xargs -r0 chmod a=rw
```

Portably, you could do:

```
find . -type f \
       ! -perm a=rw \
       -exec grep -q DATA {} ';' \
       -exec chmod a=rw {} +
```

But as that runs one `grep` per file, that would be significantly less efficient.

In any case, having world writeable data files sounds like a very bad idea.

Also beware that `chmod` follows symlinks when changing the permissions of a file, so if a file is changed from being a regular file to a symlink to `/etc/shadow` or your `~/.bashrc` (or for that matters if `./dir` in `./dir/shadow` is changed to a symlink to `/etc`) in between the time `find` finds the file and `chmod` is run, you could end up changing the permissions of the wrong file.

So you wouldn't want to run those commands in world-writeable directories.

If on a GNU/Linux system with `zsh` available, those issues can be avoided with:

```
find . -type f ! -perm a=rw -execdir zsh -c '
  zmodload zsh/system || exit
  for file do
    sysopen -o nofollow -u0 -- $file &&
      grep -q DATA &&
      chmod a=rw /dev/stdin
  done' {} +
```

Where `find` will take care of not following symlinks when descending the directory tree, and with `-execdir` the command (here `zsh`) is run from within the directory containing the found files. `zsh` takes care of opening the files without following symlinks (`nofollow` `o`ption), and `/dev/stdin` on Linux is a magic symlink to the file opened on `/dev/stdin` which should be guaranteed to point to the actual file that was opened even if it's  been removed or renamed.

---

<sup>¹ some other `grep`s now also support `-r` but few allow omitting the directory, which defaults to `.` in recent versions of GNU `grep` when `-r`/`-R` is also used.</sup>

<sup>² `-r` and `-0` are also GNU extensions, but they're widespread in other implementations nowadays, and will even be in the next version of the POSIX standard.</sup>